# Quarkus native image build fails with "Error: Already registered: java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue()"

Tags: quarkus

Using graalvm-ce-19.2.0.1 I get the following error when doing 'mvn package -Pnative'

I'm just using a sample code using maven archetype.

```
...
/home/mmusaji/Work/Quarkus/graalvm-ce-19.2.0.1/bin/native-image -J-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager -J-Drx.unsafe-disable=true -H:InitialCollectionPolicy=com.oracle.svm.core.genscavenge.CollectionPolicy$BySpaceAndTime -jar 1.0.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar -J-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1 -H:FallbackThreshold=0 -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:+PrintAnalysisCallTree -H:-AddAllCharsets -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https --enable-all-security-services -H:NativeLinkerOption=-no-pie -H:-SpawnIsolates -H:+JNI --no-server -H:-UseServiceLoaderFeature -H:+StackTrace
    [1.0.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:11330]    classlist:  10,388.45 ms
    [1.0.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner:11330]        setup:     410.46 ms
    Error: Already registered: java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue()
    com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Already registered: java.lang.reflect.Method.getDefaultValue()
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:65)
        at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.guarantee(UserError.java:86)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.register(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:708)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleMethodInAliasClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:334)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleAliasClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:298)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.handleClass(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:274)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.substitute.AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.init(AnnotationSubstitutionProcessor.java:230)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.createDeclarativeSubstitutionProcessor(NativeImageGenerator.java:875)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.setupNativeImage(NativeImageGenerator.java:824)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.doRun(NativeImageGenerator.java:524)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGenerator.lambda$run$0(NativeImageGenerator.java:444)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
    Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1

...
```

Comment: Which version of Quarkus do you use? Do you use our BOM? This error happens when the same element is substituted twice by GraalVM. I suspect this could happen if you have the wrong dependency versions. If you could share a minimal reproducer, that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Updating the pom to use later version and seems to have fixed the issue.